# Disable textarea without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would i disable a textarea without using jQuery?

Am using the following at the moment:

```
$("#textareaId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qTd9c/3/

Comment: Please make sure you don't tag jquery when you want a solution in javascript.

Comment: @user2063626 jQuery's still relevant to the the question (as opposed to only the scenario leading up to the question), so I'd say it fits.

Answer (score 4):

Simply do

```
document.getElementById("textareaId").disabled=true;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/owinew/1/edit)

jQuery is a JavaScript library, everything you do using it can be done in JavaScript, even if it's often a little more verbose or implies a greater care to browser differences. See http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: Cant get it to work :/ No error, but textarea is still selectable

Comment: What do you want ? You want the user to be unable to copy the text ? I don't think you can do that on textarea in modern webkit based browsers. You would need to put a div over the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
document.getElementById("mytxt").disabled=true;
```

Link to fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ntz2y/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with setAttribute method and check any difference in output.

```
document.getElementById("textareaId").setAttribute('disabled', true);
```